# App Drawer (RecyclerView grid) scrolling is not fast

Tags: android

I have App drawer having all apps of my device, I am using RecylerView. there are 4 columns having application icon and Application name has a item of RecylerView. But it is not fast scrolling of RecylerView like pixel or nova Launcher app drawer.
Here is my source. I am getting Icon by package name. Kindly suggest me any solution.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
    appDrawerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    gridAppDrawer = new GridAppDrawer(getContext(), applications, resArray, R.layout.item_app_drawer_pixel);
    appDrawerRecyclerView.setAdapter(gridAppDrawer);
```

adapter source

```
public class GridAppDrawer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAppDrawer.ViewHolder> {
int[] res;
int fragNo;
Context cntx;
List<RelatedAppsModeInfo> apps;
ArrayList<String> arraylist;
int layout;

public GridAppDrawer(Context mContext, List<RelatedAppsModeInfo> mApps, int[] mRes, int mLayout) {
    this.cntx = mContext;
    apps = mApps;
    res = mRes;
    layout = mLayout;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_app_drawer_pixel, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    try {
        holder.titleText.setText(apps.get(position).related_app_name);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(cntx.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(apps.get(position).related_apps_pkg_name));
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackageManager pm = cntx.getPackageManager();
                RecentAppsModeInfo recentAppsPbj = new RecentAppsModeInfo();
                recentAppsPbj.setRecentAppsInfo(0, apps.get(position).related_apps_pkg_name, apps.get(position).related_app_name);
                Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(position).related_apps_pkg_name);
                cntx.startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return apps.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleText;
    private ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the cause of slowness? Have you performed some tracking?

Comment: @azizbekian I think it is the images in the grid which make it slow.

Comment: If you comment the line `holder.image.setImageDrawable()` it works normally?

Comment: No, not smooth work even comment this line

Comment: That means the issue doesn't lie in showing pictures. Search other causes too.

Comment: I have the same problem it is scrolling smoothly if I commenting `holder.image.setImageDrawable()` , is there any alternative for this line ??